# Enumerate multi-subsets for a multiset in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a multiset (i.e., allow repeated elements), enumerate all *distinct* multi-subsets *without* using `itertools`(order is not important).

**Example:** Let `s = 'a,a,b'` then print to the console,

```
a
a,a
b
a,b
a,a,b
```

I am wondering if my approach (presented below) is efficient, and would appreciate stylistic advice. For example, I am not used to using `*args`, and in places my approach feels kludgey.

**My attempt:**

Count items in `s`:

```
A = s.split(',')
A_counts = defaultdict(int)
for i in A:
    A_counts[i] += 1
```

In our example we have `{'a':2, 'b':1}`. Use this to enumerate all tuples of points in the product of sets `range(3)`x`range(2)`, i.e., `[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,0],[2,1]]`. Each tuple corresponds to a unique multi-subset. For example, the tuple `[2,1]` corresponds to `a,a,b` and the tuple `[2,0]` corresponds to `a,a`.

Enumerate all tuples:

```
def enumerate_tuples(*args):
    res = [[i] for i in range(args[0])]
    for arg in args[1:]:
        tmp = [j + [i] for i in range(arg) for j in res]
        res = tmp
    return res
```

Now print the corresponding multi-subset to console:

```
ordered_alphabet = list(A_counts)
args = (A_counts[i] + 1 for i in ordered_alphabet)
tuples = enumerate_tuples(*args)

# cycle through tuples printing corresponding string
for tup in tuples:
    if sum(tup) == 0: continue
    group = [ordered_alphabet[i] for i in range(len(tup)) for _ in range(tup[i])]
    out = ','.join(group)
    print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It's a good idea to divide code into *functions* — this makes it easier to document, test and reuse the code. Here it would make sense to have a function defined like this:

   ```
   def sub_multisets(elements):
       "Generate the sub-multisets of the iterable elements."
       # code goes here
   ```

   Then you could call `sub_multisets(s.split(','))` or whatever in the main program.
2. The code in the post omits one of the sub-multisets, namely the *empty* sub-multiset.
3. Wherever you have code using `defaultdict(int)`, consider using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead. This is a specialized data structure for counting things. Here you could write:

   ```
   A_counts = Counter(s.split(','))
   ```

   with no need for a loop.
4. To compute the Cartesian product of some collections, use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Here we need something like:

   ```
   product(*[range(n + 1) for n in A_count.values()])
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   >>> A_count = Counter('aab')
   >>> list(product(*[range(n + 1) for n in A_count.values()])
   [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
   ```

   which are the sub-multiset counts required.
5. To build the sub-multiset, we can use the [`Counter.elements`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) method, for example if we have the counts `(1, 1)` we can write:

   ```
   >>> tuple(Counter(dict(zip(A_count.keys(), (1, 1)))).elements())
   ('a', 'b')
   ```

   Another way to do this would be to use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

   ```
   >>> tuple(chain.from_iterable(repeat(k, n) for k, n in zip(A_count.keys(), (2, 1))))
   ('a', 'a', 'b')
   ```

   but I think the `Counter.elements` approach is slightly simpler.

Putting all this together:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

def sub_multisets(elements):
    """Generate the sub-multisets of the iterable elements.
    For example:

    >>> [''.join(s) for s in sub_multisets('aab')]
    ['', 'b', 'a', 'ab', 'aa', 'aab']

    """
    counts = Counter(elements)
    for sub_counts in product(*[range(n + 1) for n in counts.values()]):
        yield Counter(dict(zip(counts.keys(), sub_counts))).elements()
```

Comment: There is a requirement from OP to not use itertools. I agree knowing how to use itertools is good, but could you provide an alternative in each place you've used it?

Comment: Not without knowing the reason for the requirement, no. (The [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has recipes which you could use instead of importing the corresponding function—look for the phrase "roughly equivalent to"—but why would you want to do that?)

Comment: A learning experience? ("I want to write it myself", "My assignment says I can't use itertools") Writing code for a different implementation of python that maybe come with itertools out of the box? Those both seem like reasonable scenarios where you don't want an itertools solution.

Comment: @spyr03: You might consider writing your own answer making those points.

Answer (score 1):

1. > ```
   > A = s.split(',')
   > A_counts = defaultdict(int)
   > for i in A:
   >     A_counts[i] += 1
   > ```

   You are basicly reinventing [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and this can be rewrote to

   ```
   counts = Counter(s.split(','))
   ```
2. Why the string to tuple conversion?

   I am not sure why you are converting the input into tuples and then convert them back into strings corresponding the input again. Because you could have iterated over the `a,a,b` without the conversion
3. Use libraries when possible

   I know you specifically said not to use `itertools` lib, but this seems the perfect spot to use it. If there is no specific reason for it (like an assignment) I recommend using it.

---

```
iterable = s.split(',')
multisets = set()
for r in range(1, len(iterable)+1):
    for comb in combinations(iterable, r):
        out = ','.join(comb)
        if out not in multisets:
            multisets.add(out)
            print(out)
```

Here is another approach, directly iterating over the string. And making combinations of them, lastly checking for distinct values by comparing to the `multiset` set

Comment: Regarding 2.: I'm not sure if I misunderstood what you mean, but iterating over the string `'a,a,b'` would also include the commas and the item count would be 5, not 3. So it does make sense to use e.g. tuples as internal representation, and convert from/to strings for input and output.

Comment: @mkrieger I meant iterating after the split happens, and making combinations of the list `['a', 'a', 'b']`